# PySpark - Reading SequenceFile and convert it to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples

I've a SequenceFile in HDFS and I want to transform to a dataframe and insert into a table. I'm having some trouble on the conversion part.

I've this code:

```
myseqFile = sc.sequenceFile("/user/sequencefile")
```

And I got the following structure:

```
(u' 10', u' 10,34,Center,Tatic')
```

And I need to get the following dataframe:

```
10,10,34,Center,Tatic
```

For that I am trying with the following code:

```
res=myseqFile .map(lambda x: tuple(x)).map(lambda x: str(x).split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]))
```

But I am still getting the same results:

```
(u' 10', u' 10,34,Center,Tatic')
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
res=myseqFile .map(lambda x: x[0] + ',' + x[1]).map(lambda x: str(x).split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]))
```